# как выделять TextInput слева при использовании inputmask в qml

Tags: qml, inputmask

Сделал фронт страницы авторизации, авторизация сделана по номеру и коду подтверждения.
Проблема заключается в том, что по идее нужно, чтобы текстовое поле выделялось слева а не в том месте куда ты именно кликнул. в обычных текстовых полях без маски всё работает хорошо, но если её создать то происходит то, что я описал. InputMask у меня задаётся с помощью Combobox, выглядит это на данный момент так:

```
            ComboBox
            {

                editable: false
                id: inputСountry
                font.pointSize: 16
                height: parent.height * 1.2
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                implicitWidth: parent.width


                model: ListModel{
                id: inputСountryModel
                ListElement{text:  "Россия"}
                ListElement{text:  "Белоруссия"}


                }

                onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                    let CountyNumber = new Map();

                    CountyNumber.set("Россия", "+ 7 (000) 000 00 00");
                    CountyNumber.set("Белоруссия", "+ 375 (000) 000 00 00");
                    for ( let Country of CountyNumber){
                        Country = Array.from(CountyNumber.keys())

                        switch(inputСountryModel.get(currentIndex).text){
                        case Country[0]:{inputNumber.inputMask =  CountyNumber.get(Country[0]); inputNumber.text=""; break;}
                        case Country[1]:{inputNumber.inputMask =  CountyNumber.get(Country[1]); inputNumber.text=""; break;}
                         }
                    }

                }
            }
```

И собственно текстовое Поле TextInput, для которого и нужен Combobox который задаёт InputMask из блока кода выше:

```
    Rectangle{
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            id: backgrOfNumber
            implicitWidth: parent.width *0.99
            height: 60
            color: "#ffffff"
            radius: 4
            clip: true
        TextInput
            {
                id: inputNumber
                color: "#000000"
                font.pointSize: 20
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                anchors.fill: parent
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                anchors.left: parent
                anchors.leftMargin: 10
                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly


            }
        }
```

Чтобы решить проблему пробовал использовать сигнал (вернее его обработчик) onTextEdited
и методы selectAll(), moveCursorSelection, selectionStart, не исключаю, что при чтении документации я не правильно понял как работает сигнал TextEdited.
Думал сделать вместо маски Label для TextInput, но прикинул, что post запрос в таком случае скорее всего выйдет сильно нагруженным, по этому решил отказаться от этой мысли, да и костыльно это очень как-то.